# What are the applications available to monitor a user screen activity?

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring

Is there any application available to monitor a user screen activity for Ubuntu 12.04? Preferably in hidden mode so logged in user may not be able to find out if the user screen is being monitored (assuming the user is an average user with minimal/zero commands knowledge).

I guess VNC is one way but I want to make sure that's the best option.

Comment: [GreeenLog](http://greeennotebook.com/2010/07/greeenlog-keylogger-and-web-monitor-for-linux/)?

Comment: You're planning to do nasty things, aren't you? And you want the help of the community to do them, to an unexperienced user, amongst other things. Nope, you won't have my help.

Comment: @Avio No problem! Your help is not needed anyway.

Comment: @Avio if you downvoted this questions please read the faq on downvoting. Disagreeing with a question is not a reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Epoptes**  is an open source computer lab management and monitoring tool. It allows for screen broadcasting and monitoring, remote command execution, message sending, imposing restrictions like screen locking or sound muting the clients and much more!

It can be installed in Ubuntu, Debian and openSUSE based labs that may contain any combination of the following: LTSP servers, thin and fat clients, non LTSP servers, standalone workstations, NX or XDMCP clients et

[image]

[image: Download for ubuntu]

You can find also some specialized software such as :

**School Calendar**:  School Calendar is a universal calendar for teachers and pupils from high-schools and colleges, letting them track lessons and tasks to do, organize the studies more effectively than before.

**Educator**: Educator is software for classroom management. It enables teachers to present their work to all students in classroom without using projector. With Educator, teacher can take full control over student

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I wish they add recording of user activity as well in future.

Comment: you are welcome, dont forget to upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with italc or epoptes.